# Add +/- to make a numeric string evaluated in 0

Tags: algorithm

Given a string consisting of number, add + or - sign to make the expression values 0. Return the expression.

For example,

123 => 1 + 2 -3 = 0

173956 => 17 + 39 - 56 = 0

I have no clues to solve this problem other than a brute-force way.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe http://math.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask this.

Comment: Did you look at Dynamic Programming for solving it?

Comment: I tried dynamic programming, but it is a little bit difficult to get an optimal substructure.

Comment: You can reduce the possibilities some by using even/odd testing (first dividing all the digits by their gcd). There must be an even number of odd final digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a search problem. Search must be performed in the solution space.
Suppose we starting from '123' string, at this point, we can add + or - sign after '1', as result we get '1 + 23' or '1 - 23'. Every variant can be split further by adding a sign after next character. As result, all possible sign additions will form tree-like structure - the solution space. Your algorithm must search solution in this structure. I think A* can be used to do this.

[Anders K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45685/anders-k) draw nice ASCII graph of the solution space, you just need to search it for solution. Simple breadth first search or depth first search can do the work, but I think it will be slow if solution space is large.

Also, I think that is possible to find more optimal, specific solution that exploits properties of the solution space, for example - it's tree-like structure.

Comment: Thank you, but I think Anders K has missed one branch, (+|-|concat), right?

Comment: Yes, if this is the case, solution space will be a graph.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it in many ways for example using a recursive approach which becomes obvious if you structure it up as a tree

e.g. 123

since there can be two different signs after a digit digit `(+|-)`  :

```
        1
       / \
      +   -
     /     \
    2       2   
   / \     / \
  +   -   +   -
  |   |   |   |
  3   3   3   3
```